# Drupal-8 best security settings

Tags: drupal-8

I'm quite new to Drupal-8 and want to ensure that the security of my company's website is strong. Are there any tips on what settings to change in admin panel?

My company use Windows Server 2016 if this is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is webserver hardening , database hardening and site hardening and many other things.  Since you asked very broad topic, first figure out what part you want focus on (if you on hosting plan or own your server etc).
Having said that , below are site security best practices.

https://www.drupal.org/security/secure-configuration

Code and configuration security

https://www.drupal.org/docs/security-in-drupal